# moving from exceptional to airbrake, any substitue for .context?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, airbrake

I am trying to move from exceptional to airbrake.io

as that is the recommendation from exceptional.

the one place I currently have a problem with is the before filter I have on my applcation_controller which has the following code:

```
Exceptional.context(
      plan_id: current_plan.try(:id)
    )
```

this sets a "context" for exceptional and it will pass this important parameter on every exception.

How can I do the same in airbrake? I couldn't find any similar option. 
only to pass my extra parameters as part of the hash. which is only possible if I am the one making the call for airbrake with: `Airbrake.notify`
but what I want this param to be sent on every exception in general?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be possible. I'm not sure Airbrake supports custom data.
The `notify` method has an [`options` hash parameter](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/master/lib/airbrake.rb#L130-L132), but it's not intended to accept arbitrary key-values.